# There is no graph $G$ with $0<χ_f(G)<1$ or $1<χ_f(G)<2$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

There is no graph $G$ with $0<χ_f(G)<1$ or $1<χ_f(G)<2$.

$χ_f$ is the fractional chromatic number

Comment: Presumably, $\chi_f$ is the fractional chromatic number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is easy: for any $b$-fold coloring with at least one vertex, we must use at least $b$ colors.  So, if $\chi_f \neq 0$, then $\chi_f \geq b/b = 1$.

The second part is a bit trickier, but still straightforward. Note that if $\chi_f > 1$, then $\chi > 1$, which means that our graph has at least one edge. Show that any $b$-fold coloring of the vertices on that edge uses at least $2b$ colors, from which we conclude that $\chi_f \geq (2b)/b = 2$.

Comment: That depends; what part is confusing to you? Is there a phrase I've used that you don't understand?

Comment: @Ogi if you really understand what you're supposed to prove but don't know how to show it, then it seems to me that you don't really understand what a $b$-fold coloring is. If it helps, I'm asking you to show that $\chi_f(K_2) = 2$. Try coming up with $b$-fold colorings for $b = 2,3,4$. Check the definition to make sure that your coloring is really a valid coloring.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?